# how to pass a php variable using ng-click

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs

I have a foreach loop using php inside that loop im passing three parameters. the problem is when i do a console log the variable being passed the consoles says there undefined, but in the html i can see the html output with the variable being there.

this is my html

```
<tbody><?php
   foreach($rows as $row):?>
       <tr class="odd gradeA">
            <td><a href="#"><?=$row->firstName?> <?=$row->lastName?></a></td>
            <td><?=$row->address . ' ' . $row->city . ' ' . $row->state . ' ' . $row->zipCode?></td>
            <td><?=$row->email?></td>
            <td><?=$row->cellPhone?></td>
            <td class="text-right tableIcons">
                <a title="Edit User" href="users/edit/<?=$row->userId?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
                <button ng-click="remove(<?=$row->firstName?>, <?=$row->lastName?>, <?=$row->userId?>)" title="Remove User" href="#" class="userRemove btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
            </td>
       </tr><?php
   endforeach?>
</tbody>
```

when i press the ng-click i want to get those 3 arguments being passed. it the html view source i can see the values of all three.

```
    $scope.remove = function(firstName, lastName, userId){

    console.log(firstName);

    $scope.firstName = firstName;
    $scope.lastName = lastName;


    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
        templateUrl: 'remove.html',
        controller: function($scope, $modalInstance){
            $scope.cancel = function () {
                $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
            };
        }
    })

};
```

the console.log(firstName) says that the value is undefined. now what an I doing wrong why cannot get those values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `"`.

Try like this:

```
        <button ng-click="remove('<?=$row->firstName?>', '<?=$row->lastName?>', '<?=$row->userId?>')" title="Remove User" href="#" class="userRemove btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
```

Comment: @user3862830 If the answer is useful you can up vote, and if the answer solve your problem you can accept it. For more info read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers